# Array Not Updating in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

so what i'm attempting to do is, get the data entered in forms and store them in their respective variables within an object. After that I want to append said object to an empty array and repeat the process. using the **function** *showMe()*., i want to print value at specified index. However, no matter the index i set, it only gives me the value of last item added to the array. Where did i go wrong??

```
var USERS = [];



var user= {

    firstName: "None",
    lastName : "None",
    age : 0,
    bodyType : "None",
    height : 0,
    bdayDay : 0,
    bdayMonth : "None",
    bdayYear : 0,
    gender: "None"

};

function addnew(){


   user.firstName = document.getElementById("fname").value;

   user.lastName =  document.getElementById("lname").value;

   user.age = document.getElementById("age").value;

   if (document.getElementById("genMale").checked)
        user.bodyType = document.getElementById("btMale").value;
   else
        user.bodyType = document.getElementById("btFemale").value;;


user.height = document.getElementById("Height").value;

    if (document.getElementById("genMale").checked)
        user.gender =  document.getElementById("genMale").value;
    else 
        user.gender = document.getElementById("genFemale").value;

    USERS.push(user);


}

function showMe(){

console.log(USERS[1].firstName);
}
```

Comment: when are you calling all this methods? an event?

Comment: yes I'm calling it on an event onclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one global variable `user` in your code.

I think you want to do object-oriented style, where your `var user` is a *prototype*. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects).

Apart from that, eykjs' solution is correct. Your quick solution is that the variable must be initialized inside the function:

```
function addnew(){
    var user = {
    ...
```

The reason your code doesn't work is that in JavaScript, objects are passed by reference, which essentially means that if you assign one object to another variable, they will be the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize the user object directly in the addNew function and not outside:

```
function addNew(){

   var user= {
        firstName: "None",
        lastName : "None",
        age : 0,
        bodyType : "None",
        height : 0,
        bdayDay : 0,
        bdayMonth : "None",
        bdayYear : 0,
        gender: "None"
    };
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create an object, push it to an array, and then further edit the object, you edit the object in the array as well because the array just holds a reference to the object.

For example:

```
var obj = {
    name:'mark'
}

var arr = [obj]
console.log(arr)
// [ { name: 'mark' } ]

obj.name= "tom"
console.log(arr)
//[ { name: 'tom' } ]
```

You are overwriting your object in the array every time. You can instead do something like:

```
function addnew(){
   var user = {}
   user.firstName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
   // etc.
}
```

To create a new object every time the function runs.

Alternatively you could use an approach where you define a constructor function and call `new` when you want to create an object:

```
function User(){
    this.firstName = "None"
    this.lastName = "None"
    this.age = 0
    this.bodyType = "None",
    this.height = 0
    this.bdayDay = 0
    this.bdayMonth = "None"
    this.bdayYear = 0
    this.gender = "None"
}

function addnew(){
   var user = new User()
   user.firstName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
   // etc.
}
```

This has the advantage of later being able to organize behavior by defining methods on the User prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Use a constructor:

```
function User(firstNameElement, lastNameElement, ageElement) {
  this.firstName = document.querySelector(firstNameElement).value
  this.lastName = document.querySelector(lastNameElement).value
  this.age = document.querySelector(ageElement).value
}
```

call `new User(firstNameElement, lastNameElement, ageElement)` when the user submits the form.

Methods like `showFirstName` can be placed in the prototype to save memory like so:

```
User.prototype.showFirstName = function() {
  return this.firstName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I think that [@Mark_M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3874623/mark-m) has the reasoning about why this is failing I wanted to offer another option for fixing it. Instead of using a function as a constructor for a new object I would recommend a new object literal instead. Maybe something like:

```js
var USERS = [];
var defaultUser= {
    firstName: "None",
    lastName : "None",
    age : 0,
    bodyType : "None",
    height : 0,
    bdayDay : 0,
    bdayMonth : "None",
    bdayYear : 0,
    gender: "None"
};

function addnew(){
   const newUser = {
       firstName: document.getElementById("fname").value,
       lastName:  document.getElementById("lname").value,
       age: document.getElementById("age").value,
       height: document.getElementById("Height").value,
       gender: document.getElementById("genMale").checked
           ? document.getElementById("genMale").value
           : document.getElementById("genFemale").value,
       bodyType: document.getElementById("genMale").checked
           ? document.getElementById("btMale").value
           : document.getElementById("btFemale").value
   };

   USERS.push(
       Object.assign(defaultUser, newUser); //creates a new object with defaults
   );
}

function showMe(){
    console.log(USERS[1].firstName);
}
```